Adaptive layout of 3 elements without duplicating HTML elements. Is it even possible?
How to swap blocks 2 and 3 on a small screen? Without duplicating HTML tags, and the desktop layout of the blocks is not broken. No position absolute.


.wrap {
    display: flex;
}
.col {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.el {
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.one {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #8BAFED;
}
.two {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #FEDDCC;
}
.three {
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #FF7100;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .wrap {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="el one">1</div>
        <div class="el two">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="el three">3</div>
    </div>
</div>



jsfiddle.net
There should be no empty space between block 1 and 3 on the big screen

The HTML structure in your fiddle is different than the one you have shown here, so which one is it actually?

You should probably look into grid instead of flexbox.

can you provide some (mock-up) images of your expected results.

Awesome, found display: contents
https://jsfiddle.net/pghv51n8/10/
